# PGFPlots package does not show any graphs

Tags: pdftex, lyx, luatex

As I told in my previous thread, I'm trying to find my way out with the `PGFPlots` package. The package is installed and I added `\usepackage{pgfplots}` in the Latex Preamble section. I pressed the `TeX` box and inserted the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As shown in the image: (The document contains also some lines written in Hebrew - RTL language)

[image]

I compiled the `LyX` document with `pdflatex` and it shows an empty page (without any errors). But if I'll compile it with `LuaTex` it will show the following errors:

[image]

And if i'll press `show output anyway`, it will show the wanted graph (as shown in the image), but it will make the hebrew words **reverse**.

[image]

I prefer to use `pdflatex` because its the default option (and it keeps the Hebrew words right). How can I make `pdflatex` accept and show the graphs? I also the other formats but none of them showed the graph.

**EDIT**: The `MWE`:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass heb-article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
customHeadersFooters
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip smallskip
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1.0] 
\backslash
begin{axis} [xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f(x)$, width=10cm, grid=major] 
\backslash
addplot [blue, line width = 1, smooth, domain=-2:2] {3*x^2 + 5*x - 2}; 
\backslash
end{axis} 
\backslash
end{tikzpicture}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: @Raven thank you for the replay. I have added the `MWE` with a better example.

Comment: @scottkosty I added those two lines (although I don't understand how they help).

Comment: regarding "although I don't understand how they help", did you test your original minimal example? LyX says "not a readable LyX document". Different LyX versions have different file formats since they have different features. When opening a .lyx file, LyX needs to know what format the file is in. In addition, it's useful because it seems you forgot to specify your LyX version. For LyX bugs/questions, please always specify your LyX version.

Comment: Is this issue related to Hebrew? That is, can you reproduce the issue without anything related to Hebrew (e.g., "Hebrew Article" class in your .lyx file)? I suggest you make your MWE as minimal and "vanilla" as possible. I can reproduce your issue with LyX 2.3.2. I don't think this info helps you much, but at least you know that upgrading to newest version of LyX will not fix your issue. I suggest to create a corresponding .tex MWE in LyX by going to File > Export > LaTeX (pdflatex). This will help the LaTeX experts around here help you (most of them do not use LyX).